# How to teach an AI to race optimally in a racing game?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, game-ai, path-finding

I play a racing game called Need For Madness ( some gameplay: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NC5uFZ-t0A8 ). NFM is a racing game, where the player can choose different cars and race and crash the other cars, and you can play on different tracks too. The game has a fixed frame rate, so you can assume that the same sequence of button presses will always arrive at the exact same position, rotation, velocity, etc. of the car.

I want to make a bot which could race faster than I can. What would be the best way to go about doing this? Is this problem even suited for deep learning?

I was thinking I could train a neural network where the input would be the current world state (position of the player, position of the checkpoints you have to through and all the obstacles), and the output would be an array of booleans, one for each button. During a race, I could then keep forward propagating from the input to the booleans. However, I'm not so sure what I would do after the race is over. How do I back propagate after the race to make the NN be less likely to make bad moves?